# Unable to have fixed form field postions while dynamically adding new fileds in a form

Tags: css, jquery-ui, show-hide, forms, html-table

I have a simple password reset dialog, which enables users to set a custom password.

```
<form id="resetPassword"
action="XXXXX">
<fieldset><input type="hidden" name="userId" value="${user.id}" />
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><input id="resetCustomPassword" class="ui-widget" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><label>Set Custom Password</label></td>     
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody style="display: none;">
<tr>
    <td><label for="newPassword"> New Password: </label></td>
    <td><input id="newPassword" class="ui-widget" type="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="reTypeNewPassword"> Retype New Password: </label></td>      
    <td><input id="reTypeNewPassword" class="ui-widget" type="password"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Now, if a user checks for "Set Custom password", I dynamically show the new password fields. The problem is in my this label in the above form:

```
 <td><label>Set Custom Password</label></td>
```

This gets dynamically adjusted to the RIGHT side, so it aligns with the new password fields.
How can I let my above label be static, and not adjust itself dynamically?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope this is just an example and you aren't actually doing this: `<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="${user.id}" />` because if you are I can change everyone's password.  The server should know the userId and not depend on the form to pass it back.

Comment: Yes. you are right Stephen. Just copy pasted an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<td align="left"><label>Set Custom Password</label></td>
```

You're far better off using styled unordered lists as containers for forms, rather than tables.

See: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists